# Does seller or buyer pay for business trips?

Tags: travel

Is it common, or even standard, for the selling company instead of the buying company to pay for travel expenses, when a representative from the buying company visits the seller? I am thinking of expenses such as flight tickets and hotel expenses. Is it unpolite to request that as a condition for the visit?

Both companies are in Europe, in case that matters.

Comment: I see that someone has cast a negative vote. Please tell me why, or if there is a better forum for this question.

Comment: I have never heard of a client or potential client requesting reimbursement for their travel expenses. Nor have I ever hear d of a client paying the expenses of a sales team to visit them although they often pay for travel expenses of employees of the other company once a contract is in place.

Comment: It depends on the industry and on how much leverage you have in the potential relationship. If you're a medical doctor or work for a hospital, for instance, some (selling) companies will even offer to fly you (and your loved ones) to the Bahamas to sell you on their medical devices. Please tell us the industry you're in and the actual power you have in your company to make decisions. Of course, you'll have to consult with the ethics guidelines of your own company, because some of those trips could be considered thinly disguised bribes and could unduly influence your purchase decisions.

Comment: It is a professional trip to a non-fancy destination (their factory). It is on their invite.

Comment: certainly in the UK I've always known the general rule to be that in a pre-contract stage the cost of travel etc is the responsibility of the traveling party

Comment: There is conflict of interest if the selling company pays the travelling cost. So, you'd better let the buying company pay the cost.

Comment: I would highly assume that this isn't the first case that your company has been invited. Have you asked your manager how they handled these cases in the past?

Comment: I'd recommend stepping away from speaking in general terms to make it clear what your actual question is. I assume it's "*Our vendor invited us to visit their factory, can we ask them to pay for our trip over there?*" Regardless, I would think you'd simply bring it up with your manager who should be more in tune with the norms that apply to this particular company relationship.

Comment: I am not asking about what I should do in a particular situation. The question is carefully worded: I want to know what is common overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends greatly on who is taking the most initiative in the deal or who want's the deal the most.

For example, if Contoso needs a new widget supplier and they think Fabrikam makes the best widgets in the world and really wants them, Contoso will pay to send their personnel to Fabrikam to inspect the factory and negotiate a deal.

But, if Fabrikam is trying to sell Contoso their amazing widgets and get them to switch suppliers, then Fabrikam will invite at their (Fabrikam's) expense Contoso personnel to inspect the factory and discuss a deal.

In other words, whoever has the most initiative usually pays.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Of course.